# train and test PyTorch dataloaders what to set shuffle?

Tags: pytorch

Should a test DataLoader have shuffle set to `True`?

According to this [pytorch discussion thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/shuffle-true-or-shuffle-false-for-val-and-test-dataloaders/143720) I believe the answer is no, it should be False.

The [official docs/tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) states *While training a model, we typically want to pass samples in “minibatches”, reshuffle the data at every epoch to reduce model overfitting*; which suggest just training should be `shuffle=True` However their immediate example has both set to True.

Any guidance would be helpful.

The reason I ask is I have mine set to True; but my test accuracy is terrible.

```
Epoch: 1 | Train Loss: 2.1650 | Train Acc: 0.4683 | Test Loss: 6.2742 | Test Acc: 0.0349
Epoch: 2 | Train Loss: 1.2008 | Train Acc: 0.6624 | Test Loss: 6.9259 | Test Acc: 0.0359
Epoch: 3 | Train Loss: 0.9474 | Train Acc: 0.7325 | Test Loss: 7.3948 | Test Acc: 0.0365
Epoch: 4 | Train Loss: 0.7897 | Train Acc: 0.7808 | Test Loss: 7.7263 | Test Acc: 0.0352
Epoch: 5 | Train Loss: 0.6799 | Train Acc: 0.8186 | Test Loss: 8.0628 | Test Acc: 0.0377
Epoch: 6 | Train Loss: 0.5953 | Train Acc: 0.8374 | Test Loss: 8.3828 | Test Acc: 0.0351
Epoch: 7 | Train Loss: 0.5269 | Train Acc: 0.8647 | Test Loss: 8.5854 | Test Acc: 0.0351
Epoch: 8 | Train Loss: 0.4693 | Train Acc: 0.8791 | Test Loss: 8.9052 | Test Acc: 0.0337
Epoch: 9 | Train Loss: 0.4234 | Train Acc: 0.8955 | Test Loss: 9.1290 | Test Acc: 0.0354
```

```
train_ds = ImageFolder(
    root=TRAIN_DIR,
    transform=pretrained_weights.transforms(),
)

test_ds = ImageFolder(
    root=TEST_DIR,
    transform=pretrained_weights.transforms(),
)

train_dl = DataLoader(
    dataset=train_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True
)

test_dl = DataLoader(
    dataset=test_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you want to set it to `True` for train. This allows the model to see more diverse batches across different epochs. At test time, it does not really matter.

I would say the reason for your low test loss is most likely unrelated to the `shuffle` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is most appreciated. Do you have any source material on test shuffle=False or True is not relevant?

Comment: [The first comment of the post you linked to](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/shuffle-true-or-shuffle-false-for-val-and-test-dataloaders/143720/2), elaborates why shuffle on the test dataset does not matter. [This post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks) explains why it is good in general to shuffle the dataset at train time.